# Visual Studio 2015 RC & Cordova build.bat: "Error: Please install Android target: "android-21""

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

**Environment**

- VS 14.0.22823.1 D14REL
- 64 bit JDK, manually installed; not using the one which comes with ADK
- Windows 8.1

**Problem**

- Create new Project of type "Appache Cordova Apps", leave default name "BlankCordovApp3"
- Build the app with default settings: Works fine
- Try to build the solution with `BlankCordovApp3\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat` in order to get more output
- Error: 
  Please install Android target: "android-21".
  Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: ...
  You will require:

  1. "SDK Platform" for android-21
  2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
  3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)]`
     [Error: Please install Android target: "android-21".
     Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: ...
     You will require:
  4. "SDK Platform" for android-21
  5. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
  6. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

- It is **not** a problem of the installed ADK levels.The problem persists even if the correct tools are installed through the Android SDK manager.
- In my case, the problem was solved by adding the adk tools to the path (Control Panel => Environment Variables).

  ```
  C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;
  ```